# How to add new filter in plp page in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Like I have added one boolean type attribute into Product table.so I want to filter on that attribute basis on my plp page.

Comment: 2) Add an additional customer attribute in Product model named as "onSale" (boolean).The customer should be able to see a facet which will filter products based on "onSale" flag.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at your `solr.impex` file.

You can add a new SolrIndexedProperty eg: 'onSale' using below code:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];facet[default=true];facetType(code);useForSpellchecking[default=false];useForAutocomplete[default=false];fieldValueProvider;valueProviderParameter
;$solrIndexedType; onSale  ;boolean;     ;     ;true ;     ;     ;MultiSelectOr ;true;true;springELValueProvider;
```

Setting the value of attribute 'onSale' can be done where other values are being set. Please do a full solr indexing after running the impex.

Comment: Will it add the filter in product listing page?

Comment: By filter, if you mean a facet, then yes. Search around solr impex, you'll get a better idea about implementation.

Comment: Hi, I added a new solrIndexedProperty for on sale and did full indexing. What's next. Sorry to ask but I am a little new in hybris solr part.so if you can help me with that

Comment: Are there any other facets already present on Product Listing page? If yes, just see how they are being implemented. For facets, you only need to set SolrIndexedProperty in solr.impex. The facets and product lists are generated using Apache SOLR, so you don't need to do anything else. Still if you face issues, search how facets are implemented on https://wiki.hybris.com/dashboard.action and https://experts.hybris.com/. You need an account to login.